# TCP/IP stack in the user context vs. kernel Linux

Tags: networking

Assuming Linux, would it be possible to implement a TCP/IP stack in the user context (vs. kernel)? How would you do it? What would be pros and cons of such an implementation, as compared to the conventional implementations where the stack resides in the kernel?

Comment: Easily: make a VM which translate TCP/IP calls from inside OS to outside via any other mechanism :) Cons are simple: slowdown because userspace passes more security and safety checks than direct kernel code, which even can rush mad easily.

Comment: But there is a related pro too: avoiding user/kernel context switches.